# App is crashing while loading a url in WebView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, transactiontoolargeexception

Hi i am trying to load a url in WebView that contains HTML. I am trying to load with

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", url, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", "");
```

But once this method is called, my app crashes with this exception.

```
:E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1110288). java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1110288 bytes
```

i have tried even using content providers, compressing the url and decompressing, but nothing has changed

Comment: You may have better luck getting help if you included a [mcve] with the *complete* stack trace and the code involved with it. Also, are you saying that if you comment out that one line and leave everything else alone that the exception does not occur?

Comment: Can you share your `code snippet`. It would help a lot identifying issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems the HTML content that you are trying to load , is too large hence you are getting exception java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1110288 bytes.

There are few possible ways that I can think of./

1. First of all see, if you can reduce HTML content size, it is better to remove redundant elements from it.
2. Instead of opening it in the app web view, can you check if you can open it in an external browser from the app itself? You can use Andriod intent functionality for this - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Something this will work

```html
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but opening in external browser is not the requirement i want to open in a webview

Comment: actually there is not any redundant things in my url so that is why i ca not reduce or remove any element from htmp string